# Adding a conditional to a crontab

Tags: shell, cron, sh

I'm having trouble understanding how to add conditionals to a cron file.

I currently just have one line that looks something like:

`0 7 * * 1 program/bin/env -e ${ENVIRONMENT_ALIAS} ${ENVIRONMENT_ROOT}/bin/pop.py`

I know a crontab file is formatted likeso:

```
minute(s) hour(s) day(s) month(s) weekday(s) command(s)
```

So would my "if" statement be after the 5 numbers above and before `program/bin/env`?

And what would the proper syntax for this if statement be?

Comment: Write a separate script and call it inside the `cron` will be safer.

Comment: Ah interesting. Could you expand a bit on why this would be safer?

Comment: You can control the script and debug it easily if something goes wrong.

Comment: Without defining the variables in the crontab it is likely to fail. In addtiion to @iamauser's comment, the outpt will be sent via mail. If you have more commands in the future it may be difficult to find out, who sent what.

Comment: Despite the warnings you might do something like `0 7 * * 1 [ ! -r /etc/DontRunCronJobs ] && { program/bin/env -e ${ENVIRONMENT_ALIAS} ${ENVIRONMENT_ROOT}/bin/pop.py; }`. Don´t forget the `;` and the space before `}` . Better to check the conditions within the Job and create a nice log somewhere.

Comment: +1 to the notion of keeping crontab files simple. For future SO searcher, be aware that cron does not (by default) have full access to all ENV vars, including $PATH. Also cron defalts to using `/bin/sh` which can bite you if you assumed Bash quoting or escaping.  It's reasonable to export custom vars to a cron job tho; just don't assume it's always "there" in your code.